# Does Swift have a spaceship operator <=>, and if not how would a custom operator be created?

Tags: swift, spaceship-operator

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaceship_operator):

> Unlike traditional equality operators, which will return true or false
>   depending on whether the arguments are equal or unequal, the spaceship
>   operator will return 1, 0, or −1 depending on the value of the left
>   argument relative to the right argument. If the left argument is
>   greater than the right argument, the operator returns 1. If the left
>   argument is less than the right argument, the operator returns −1. If
>   the two arguments are equal, the operator returns 0.

**The spaceship operator is primarily used for comparisons in sorting.**

Comment: A similar functionality in a strongly typed language like Swift, should __not__ be implemented returning an integer. It should be implemented defining an enumeration with three cases.

Answer (score 13):

Swift does not have a built-in spaceship operator, but creating new operators in swift is trivial. Let's make a new operator that returns an `enum` instead of an `Int` — [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) are [bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad) and we shouldn't need to use them for the return type in a strongly typed language. While we are at it, let's take advantage of Swift's Unicode support and make the enumeration support a visual indicator of the result using ←, →, & ↔ :

```
enum Spaceship
{
  case ← // LeftIsGreaterThanRight
  case → // LeftIsLessThanRight
  case ↔ // LeftIsEqualToRight
}

operator infix <=> {}

@infix func <=> <T: Comparable> (left: T, right: T) -> Spaceship {
  if left < right { return SpaceShip.→}
  if left > right { return SpaceShip.←}
  return Spaceship.↔;
}
```

Now you can use the new operator like this

```
if someInt <=> someOtherInt == ←
{
  // take off!
}
```

If you insist on using magic numbers as a comparison result value (which I really, really encourage you *not* to do in Swift), then here:

```
@infix func <=><T: Comparable> (left: T, right: T) -> Int {
  if left < right { return -1 }
  if left > right { return  1 }
  return 0
}
```

Comment: IMO, it would be better to use (NS)ComparisonResult which already exists in Foundation and is used in many API's.

Comment: *Technically*, it would probably be more correct to use the ComparisonResult type, but.. +1 for using unicode characters that match the 3 states so cool!!

Answer (score 3):

No, Swift currently does not include a spaceship operator.

### A Custom Spaceship Operator for Swift

A custom operator can be defined to mimic the look and function of spaceship operators in other languages.

### The Operator

Since Swift allows the use of `<`, `=` and `>` characters in custom operators, we can define a custom operator to look like this: `<=>`.

### Using the Operator

The operator is a binary infix operator and is used like this:

```
1 <=> 2   //Returns: -1
2 <=> 1   //Returns: 1
1 <=> 1   //Returns: 0
```

### Defining the Operator

The operator can be defined in Swift like this:

```
operator infix <=> {}

@infix func <=><T: Comparable> (left: T, right: T) -> Int {
  if left < right { return -1 }
  if left > right { return  1 }
  return 0
}
```

Comment: As commented on the question, this is a very bad way to implement this in a strongly typed language like Swift. You should use an enumerated type instead of an Int.

Comment: The question was specific about returning integers -1, 0, 1

Answer (score 0):

As noted by a few `ComparisonResult` already exists so can be used:

```swift
extension Comparable {
    static func <=> (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> ComparisonResult {
        if lhs < rhs { return .orderedAscending }
        if lhs > rhs { return .orderedDescending }
        return .orderedSame
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the question:

> The spaceship operator is primarily used for comparisons in sorting.

This is doubly true as it can even be used to *implement* an elegant stable sort function on top of other `Sequence` functions:

```swift
extension Sequence {
    func sorted(with comparator: (Element, Element) throws -> ComparisonResult) rethrows -> [Element]
    {
        return try enumerated()
            .sorted { (try comparator($0.element, $1.element) || $0.offset <=> $1.offset) == .orderedAscending }
            .map { $0.element }
    }
}

extension ComparisonResult {
    static func || (lhs: Self, rhs: @autoclosure () -> Self) -> ComparisonResult {
        if lhs == .orderedSame {
            return rhs()
        }
        return lhs
    }
}
```